# TYPO3 Extension Alphabetical site index - How to add additional wrap?

Tags: indexing, sitemap, typo3

**Add extra wrap in Alphabetical site index**

Situation described in the code. I think my problem is the right scope, but i don't how to solve it. Thanks a lot.

```
#
# Alphabetical site index
#
# @see  http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/cl_alphabeticalindex/0.1.3/view/toc/0/#
# @note typoscript/templates/ext/cl_alphabeticalindex/setup.ts
#
# stdWraps
#
plugin.tx_clalphabeticalindex_pi1 {
    excludeDoktypes = 5,6
    index.showEmpty = true
    list.defaultChar = A

    index_stdWrap.wrap = <ul class="alpha-index">|</ul>
    letter_stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>

    pageList_stdWrap.wrap = <ul class="alpha-index-page">|</ul>
    pageTitle_stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>

    # I Want to add inside the <li></li>
    # another wrap with the subtitle of the
    # pages <span>subtitle</span>
    # .. data = page:subtitle // page:title

    # this doesn't work
    /*
    pageTitle_stdWrap = COA
    pageTitle_stdWrap {
        10 = TEXT
        10 {
            outerWrap.cObject = COA
            outerWrap.cObject {
                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                    noTrimWrap = |<li>|</li>|
                    wrap = <li>|</li>
                    20 = TEXT
                    20 {
                        data = page:subtitle // page:title
                        innerWrap = <span>|</span>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    */

    parentTitle_stdWrap.wrap = &nbsp;( | )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
...
pageTitle_stdWrap {
    dataWrap = <span>{page:subtitle}</span>|
    wrap3 = <li>|</li>
}
...
```

http://forge.typo3.org/repositories/entry/typo3v4-core/trunk/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/class.tslib_content.php?rev=5764#L3302 is your friend :)